# How do I force a number with unknown digits behind the decimal mark?

Tags: java

Is there a way to force a number to be placed behind the decimal mark of a number?

Say I have a number = 2, and another number = 23. Is there a way for me to force 23 into 0.23, so that when I add the numbers I end up with 2.23? And is there a way to do this when the number of digits in the second number, in this case 23, are unknown?

EDIT:
I realize this was badly written. I am currently working on a program that converts from imperial units to metric units. Part of the code looks like this:

```
double feet = nextDouble();
double inches = nextDouble();
double heightInMeters = (feet + (inches/10)) / 3.2808;
```

The problem with this code is that I anticipate that the user only enters a value <0, 9> for feet. Is there a way to force the input for inches to something like 0.x where x = inches so that it doesn't matter if the number is greater than 9?

Would be lovely if it was possible without using toString() and parseInt().

Comment: convert to string. `'2' + '.' + '23'`, then parse to float?

Comment: `x / Math.pow(10, 1 + Math.floor(Math.log10(x))) == 0.x`.

Comment: Not wanting to be pedantic, but there are 12 inches in a foot, not 10, so `( feet + (inches / 10))/3.2808` gives the wrong answer.

Comment: I feel like the easier way to do this is probably something like:
http://ideone.com/heEEQi

Comment: I think my method from my answer's option 2 is easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the number of digits in an integer, `i`, using:

```
1 + Math.floor(Math.log10(i))
```

(*not* `ceil(log10(i))`, since that calculates that `1` has zero digits)

You then need to divide `i` by 10 to the power of that number:

```
i / Math.pow(10, 1 + Math.floor(Math.log10(i)))
```

e.g.

```
23 / Math.pow(10, 1 + Math.floor(Math.log10(23))) == 0.23
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/lWASle)

---

Alternatively, if you think those floating point operations `log` and `pow` are too expensive, you can determine the number of digits with a loop:

```
int d = 1;
while (d < i) d *= 10;
```

then

```
System.out.println(i / (double) d);
```

(noting that you need to cast at least one of the numerator or denominator to a floating point type, otherwise it will use integer division).

Comment: Couldn't you also use `ceil` instead of `floor` and leave off the `1 +`?

Comment: "(not ceil(log10(i)), since that calculates that 1 has zero digits)".

Comment: Thank you! The first option was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Just remember that if you're storing this in a `double`, there'll be no difference between 1 inch and 10 inches.

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing to double like this, from a string:

### Option 1

```
try
{
    int n = 2;
    int decimal = 23;
    String full = Integer.toString(n) + '.' + Integer.toString(decimal);
    double val = Double.parseDouble(full);
} catch (Exception e) //Or whatever exception 
{
    //Code
}
```

### Option 2

Of course, there are simpler methods, like this:

```
try
{
    int n = 2; 
    int decimal = 23;
    double val = Double.parseDouble(n + "." + decimal);
} catch (Exception e) //Or whatever exception 
{
    //Code
}
```

I personally would recommend the solution directly above, since it is the simplest, and requires the least code.

---

[Live Example for Second Option](http://ideone.com/Ypw11t)

Answer (score 0):

Simple implementation using Strings:

```
public class Mainclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer num = 1546;
        Integer num2 = 2;

        String s = num.toString();
        s = "0." + s;
        Double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
        System.out.println(num2+d ); // 2.1546
    }
}
```